# How can this c++ program be faster?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

Here is the link for the program: http://gpe.acm-icpc.tw/domjudge2/pct/showproblemtab.php?probid=10527&cid=5.

Here is the work I have done so far :

First, I created a function that will sort the array which is ord(a, j) in the code below.

The variable j is the size of the array that will increment every time the user input a number.

To compute the median, I have two cases.

1) if the size of the array is even, then I subtract the size of the array by 1 and divide it by 2, then the result will be the index of the sorted array plus the next element of the sorted array divided by 2 to find the median.

For example : an array of {1,3,6,2,7,8} elements. I will sort the array first which will give : {1,2,3,6,7,8} then the median will be (3+6)/2 = 4.

2) if the size of the array is odd, then I subtract the size of the sorted array by 1 and divide it by 2, the result is the index of the median.

For example : an array of {1,3,7,2,5} elements. I will sort the array first which will give : {1,2,3,5,7} then the median is 3.

```
      int* ord(int A[], int n) // function to sort the array
     {
           for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
         {
            for(int v = 0;  v < n -1; v++)
            {
              if(A[v] > A[v+1])
            {
              swap(A[v], A[v+1]); 
            }
          }
        }

        return A; 
      } 


  int main()
  {
    int a[N], x, j = 0, c; 



      while(cin >> x)
     {

       j++; // This is the size of the array


       a[j-1]=x; 

       // Below is the algorithm for finding the median


      if (j == 1) // if the array contains only one value, I just output the value
     {
      cout << a[0] << endl; 
     }
     else // if it contains more than one value then I compute the median
     { 

      ord(a, j); //sorted array 

      if (j % 2 == 0) // first case is when the size of the array is even
      { 
         // First I subtract the size of the array by 1 and divide it by 2, then c will be the index of the sorted array plus the next element of the sorted array divided by 2 to find the median

        c = (j-1) / 2; 

          cout << (a[c] + a[c+1]) / 2 << endl;
      }
      else // second case when the size of the array is odd
      {
         // First I subtract the size of the array by 1 and divide it by 2, c will be the index of the median

        c = j-1; 

        cout << a[c / 2] << endl; 
      } 

    }


  }


}
```

Comment: Use a better sort algorithm

Comment: Start by simplifying a bit. For sorting use [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), for getting the median use [std::nth_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element). Also, don't link to code. Put the code *in* the question.

Comment: Which better sort algorithm should I use @lamandy ?

Comment: If you are using STL container like std::array or std::vector, std::sort would do. If you want to implement your own, have a look at quicksort and mergesort.

Comment: The link has restricted access...

Answer (score 1):

Use a std::vector to hold your ints. Then use std::sort on it. If you have to write your own sort, try to implement a quicksort or a mergsort.

This is a fast sort via a vector and std::sort.

```
  int array_size = 8;
  int myints[] = {32,71,12,45,26,80,53,33};
  std::vector<int> myvector (myints, myints+array_size);               
  std::sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.end());
```

---

If you need to read up about faster sort algorithms:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

The general idea is to do some kind of presorting for parts of the array and then sort everything. This make the runtime log(n)*n instead of n*n. This is a major speed up, even more the bigger the numbers rise. Example:

---

log(1024)*1024 = 10*1024 = 10.240 Operations.

1024*1024 ~ 1.000.000 Operations <- 100 times slower

---

log(1.000.000)*1.000.000 = 20*1.000.000 = 20.000.000 Operations.

1.000.000*1.000.000 = 1.000.000.000.000 Operations <- 50.000 times slower

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing it wrong.
first of all you should not call the sorting function inside loop, it does the same work every time, and increasing time. It will be enough to call it once after the end of the while loop. This will drastically speed up your program.

Also inside while loop you have first incremented the value of j then you have assigned

`a[j-1] = x;`

you should first assign

`a[j] = x;`
and then `j++;`

because

`a[j-1] = x; // here j-1 will take some fraction of milliseconds to calc [j-1]`.

Hope your program will speed up.